# How to get data from a URL?

Tags: java, android, url

I have data provided in a website and it is presented as in the following image:

[image]

This website offers values of some parameters which are updated every while.
Now I want to retrieve these data according to the column name and the row number in the Android app, I know how to open http connection. But unfortunately I have no idea from where should I start and how to read the data provided in the image.

Comment: Have you any Webservice to get this Data?

Comment: The actual URL: ftp://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/pub/itrf/old/itrf92.ssc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you have a special data source to work on, you have to read the website's contents then process it manually. Here is a link from the [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) on how to read from an URL connection.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

If you are behind a proxy you should also set these system properties (to the appropriate values):

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "3.182.12.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1111");
```

Comment: but i think the code u wrote will read the whole page and i want to know how to read the table elements

Comment: Yes it reads the whole page. You can skip characters while reading until you find the table (if you know how it starts), but as I told, by default there is no way to process plain text automagically... Regexes can help once you have the site contents.

Comment: After you get the content, you can parse de html document and take only the data you need

Comment: i just have a small question, do u meaan the variable inputLine contains the data of the whole page? sorry for the silly question

Comment: @Amr reading this as whole will not be so efficient but there is no other better option, either you consider creating a web service or store the whole data on a database online

Comment: No, here you are reading line-by-line. Only if there are no line breaks in the page will one read get the whole. (I suggest you to read the docs linked.)

Comment: i tried the posted code but when i run it the console displays nothing

Comment: Are you behind a network proxy? Any exceptions? The code should work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is only clear text and the format of table doesnt change you can parse the entire table, for Example after reading the "------- ..." Line you can parse the values using a scanner:

```
 Scanner s;
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
 {
   s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(" ");
   //Then readthe Values like
   value = s.next()); // add all values in a list or array       
 } 
 s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the whole content. Couldn't you call a webservice to get this data, or directly the database which belongs to this view?